# Facebook: Trying to get custom message in popup after clicking Facebook Share Button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, message, facebook-opengraph

I know Facebook changes their algorithms all the time, so I'm not even sure this is feasible anymore. But I want to be able when I create a FB share button using OpenGraph, that the message area of the post is dynamically populated with the text of a message I want to display. And I need to do it for four share buttons I plan to place on my HTML page. So I start off with the meta tags in the head like this:

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.whatever.com/somepage.html" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="My Website" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="I just watch this webpage from #Stack" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="012345678901234" />
```

Of course, some of these properties are fillers for the actual id and url, as you might expect.

Then I add this is the body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and finally the code to generate one of the buttons:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="ttps://www.whatever.com/somepage.html" data-layout="button"></div>
```

That works to bring the share dialog popup up, but the message area is blank and I need it filled. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Prefilling is not allowed. The message area is for the user to type a message

Comment: That sucks. You can definitely do it in Twitter.